# Vtiger Product images are not showing in Product Image Information:

Tags: php, crm, vtiger

I am new to vtiger and i am using `vtiger CRM 5.4.0`. When i add an image to product it doesn't display in its detail view.Images getting uploaded and inserting to database i think the problem is with listing part. I found a code in side product module DetailView.php

`smarty->assign('BLOCKS', getBlocks($currentModule,'detail_view','',$focus->column_fields));`

from where all blocks are coming but i don't know from where all the product images are listing. Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

First confirm the images saved in the proper directory which is created dynamic in the vTiger.

Directory Path: http://example.com/storage/2013/November/week3/image_name.png

If your are uploading the files on the live server, set the folder/directory permission.

and then Create a new product and upload the file again.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue modify the file `vtlib\Vtiger\Functions.php` and add (aprox in line 196) this function:

`if($mimeType == ''){ $mimeType = $file_details['type']; }`

Example:

```
Before:
194:    //mime type check
195:    $mimeType = mime_content_type($file_details['type']);
196:
197:    $mimeTypeContents = explode('/', $mimeType);

After:
194:    //mime type check
195:    $mimeType = mime_content_type($file_details['type']);
196:    if($mimeType == ''){ $mimeType = $file_details['type']; }
197:    $mimeTypeContents = explode('/', $mimeType);
```

Regards.